# what should i do with pandas Data Reader string Error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I want to take yahoo btc/usd data but this error a occurred

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt


crypto = 'BTC'
against_crypto = 'USD'
start = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

>>> data = web.DataReader(f'{crypto}-{against_crypto}', 'yahoo', start, end)

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in data. It should be data = web.DataReader(f'{crypto}/{against_crypto}', 'yahoo', start, end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try directly with `yfinance` module, maybe it can solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd  # 2.0.0
import yfinance as yf  # 0.1.70
import datetime as dt

crypto = 'BTC'
against_crypto = 'USD'
start = dt.date(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.date.today()

df = yf.download(f'{crypto}-{against_crypto}', start=start, end=end)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                    Open          High           Low         Close     Adj Close       Volume
Date                                                                                         
2017-12-31  12897.700195  14377.400391  12755.599609  14156.400391  14156.400391  12136299520
2018-01-01  14112.200195  14112.200195  13154.700195  13657.200195  13657.200195  10291200000
2018-01-02  13625.000000  15444.599609  13163.599609  14982.099609  14982.099609  16846600192
2018-01-03  14978.200195  15572.799805  14844.500000  15201.000000  15201.000000  16871900160
2018-01-04  15270.700195  15739.700195  14522.200195  15599.200195  15599.200195  21783199744
...                  ...           ...           ...           ...           ...          ...
2023-04-18  29449.091797  30470.302734  29154.849609  30397.552734  30397.552734  19480529496
2023-04-19  30394.187500  30411.054688  28669.898438  28822.679688  28822.679688  24571565421
2023-04-20  28823.683594  29076.400391  28037.257812  28245.988281  28245.988281  21340360360
2023-04-21  28249.230469  28349.968750  27177.365234  27276.910156  27276.910156  20759504330
2023-04-22  27265.894531  27872.142578  27169.570312  27817.500000  27817.500000  13125734602

[1939 rows x 6 columns]
```